# Object performance, what is better long items or many items?

Tags: javascript, performance, events, long-integer

I've to record some events into an json-object, so what is better from performance point of view, **long** or **many** sub-objects?

For better interpretation take a look at these two objects:

**1st** (long objects)

```
var eventsObj = {
  target: {
    timestamp1: window,
    timestamp2: document,
    timestamp3: document
  },
  keyCode: {
    timestamp1: 0,
    timestamp2: 66,
    timestamp3: 67
  },
  mouseX: {
    timestamp1: 1,
    timestamp2: 2,
    timestamp3: 3
  },
  mouseY: {
    timestamp1: 0,
    timestamp2: 1,
    timestamp3: 2
  }
  ...etc...
};
```

**2nd** (many objects)

```
var eventsObj = {
  timestamp1: {
    target: window,
    keyCode: 0,
    mouseX: 1,
    mouseY: 0
  },
  timestamp2: {
    target: document,
    keyCode: 66,
    mouseX: 2,
    mouseY: 1
  },
  timestamp3: {
    target: document,
    keyCode: 67,
    mouseX: 3,
    mouseY: 2
  }
  ...etc...
};
```

**Update**

http://jsperf.com/object-performance-long-items-or-many-items

Comment: For performance it will depend what you're doing with the data. To me (particularly as a database guy) the second form is better as all data about an object is contained within it

Comment: Try http://jsperf.com/ if all you care about  is performance, and not design. "Better" is subjective, and better performance is not always "better".

Comment: @timc I'll iterate over them to reproduce some events...

Comment: @WesleyMurch Good idea, will i do now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of memory consumption, both will be (almost) identical. Performance depends on how you intend to iterate and consume the object.

However, the second representation is far more readable and semantically correct.

Comment: I'll iterate over them to reproduce some events... Can you explain your thoughts about *almost* a bit?

Comment: Memory footprint will be identical if you calculate it using `(num of characters) * (size of char)`. Difference in encoding might cause a slight difference (hence the almost) but we're talking about < 0.1% (ballpark figure).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the 2nd, because you'll probably end up wih several statements including one or several loops in the first case for getting one event's data ; whereas only one 'for...in' loop in the second case will be enough for retreiving a single event's data